# Error en join y felt join para mas de 4 tablas

Tags: join

Necesitaba rescatar información de 5 tablas las cuales estaba funcionado correctamente con los join tuve que agregar nuevas columnas de 2 tablas extras las cuales si le hago un join, me doy cuenta que elimina líneas de la consulta ya que las nuevas tablas no trae  información para realizar el join, lo cual, ingrese left join para que trajera toda la información de la tabla izquierda y me complete con la información null los campos que no estén en las otras tablas`
Quizas estoy cometiendo un error muy simple, ya que, todo lo que aprendido es gracias a youtube

*

> `ALTER VIEW Tabla_nueva  As select DOCDE_DB.NUMRECOR, DOCDE_DB.NCODART, DOCDE_DB.CTACTBLE, DOCDE_DB.CANTIDAD as Cantdoc, DOCDE_DB.PRECUNIT, DOCDE_DB.NUMOT, DOCU_DB.TIPODOC, DOCU_DB.NUMFACT, DOCU_DB.FECHA, DOCU_DB.RUTFACT, CLIEN_DB.RAZSOC, ART_DB.CODIGO as codigoart, ART_DB.NOMBRE, PLAN_DB.CODIGO as codigocta,  PLAN_DB.NOMBRE as nombrecta, OCDET_DB.NUMOT as NroOT, OC_DB.NUMOC, OCDET_DB.CANTIDAD, OCDET_DB.PRECUNIT as unioc , OC_DB.TOTNETO from DOCDE_DB, DOCU_DB, CLIEN_DB, ART_DB, PLAN_DB, OC_DB DOCDE_DB LEFT JOIN DOCDE_DB ON DOCDE_DB.SQOCDET = OCDET_DB.SEQOCDET where DOCDE_DB.NUMRECOR=DOCU_DB.NUMREG AND DOCU_DB.NRUTFACT=CLIEN_DB.NREGUIST AND DOCDE_DB.NCODART=ART_DB.NREGUIST AND DOCDE_DB.CTACTBLE=PLAN_DB.NREGUIST AND DOCDE_DB.SQOCDET = OCDET_DB.SEQOCDET AND  OCDET_DB.NUMRECOR = OC_DB.NUMREG AND DOCU_DB.FECHA >='01/05/2022' AND DOCU_DB.TIPODOC IN (8,10) AND PLAN_DB.CODIGO <> '410114'`

- 

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Difícil sin tener todo un ambiente con la DB montada :-S